# How to create Flask-ldap3-login

Tags: python, authentication, flask, ldap, flask-login

I am using flask-ldap3-login. The flask_login works well and now we want to use the ldap of our company.
So I am really new to this part. With flask-login everything works well. But with flask-ldap3-login I cannot acces.

**show_usermanagement.html**

```
{{ get_flashed_messages() }}
    {{ form.errors }}
    <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
        <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h3>
        <label>Username{{ form.username() }}</label>
        <label>Password{{ form.password() }}</label>
        {{ form.submit() }}

    </form>
```

**index.py**

```
from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager
...

Base = automap_base()
app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
...

# Setup LDAP Configuration Variables
# Hostname of your LDAP Server
app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'ldap://ska11-wn-dc01.xxx.xxx.de'

app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=de'

app.config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = 'ou=users'

app.config['LDAP_SEARCH_BASE'] = 'ou=Standorte,dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=de'

#app.config['LDAP_GROUP_DN'] = 'ou=groups'

app.config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'cn'

app.config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'mail'

app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = None

app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = None

app.config['LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE'] = 'SUBTREE'


login_manager = LoginManager(app)
ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager(app)
```

**init.py**

```
@login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        if id in users:
        return users[id]
        return None

    @ldap_manager.save_user
    def save_user(dn, username, data, membership):


        user = Users(dn, username, data)
        users[dn] = user
        return user

    @app.route("/usermanagement", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def show_usermanagement():
    form = LDAPLoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("You are logged in", 'success')
        login_user(form.user)
        return redirect('/')  # Send them home
    else:
        flash("You are not logged in. Please check your credentials!", 'danger')
```

**Inside the brower I get this response:**
['You are not logged in. Please check your credentials!'] {'csrf_token': ['The CSRF token is missing.']}
But I am not sure the reason for this. I saw different things on this issue (wrong LDAP Configuration Variables ...)
I never had any problems with csrf by using flask_login!?
Is it maybe a problem that our ldaps port is using 636?

Hope anyone can help me???

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your index is mixed with the init file (btw, should be __init.__py)

Seems like a problem with CSRF, not LDAP.

Try adding the below to your config:

`app.config["WTF_CSRF_ENABLED"] = False`

and see if that works.